# Refreshing server repository after server files have been changed

Tags: svn, repository

We have a server with svn acting as source control for a set of directories.
In an emergency, someone directly edited the files using vi.

How do I move the changes that they made outside of svn into the svn repository?
Then I'd do an "update" on the local working copies ... right?

Comment: also, the a number of new files were added to the dir structure ... how do I merge those new files into svn?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can have a fresh working copy, copy the files on the server to the working copy and commit the modifications.